# Is it possible to convert android application in eclipse to ios Rim windows using codename one?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, codenameone

I have written an application  in eclipse for android and its working fine !!

I would like to send ios Rim and windows build using code name one Is it possible ?  or do i have to write the whole code from scratch as a New Codename one project?

I tried directly sending my application using code name send android build but i got error.

Error log
[javac] C:\Documents and Settings\0mkar\My Documents\Downloads\Compressed\android\android\src\com\android\Log_SC.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    [javac]               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BufferedWriter

Full Error log 
http://www.mediafire.com/?evb4ex8lg8054ja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you will need to adapt your code to use Codename One features only and need to rewrite your UI/networking code. E.g. `BufferedWriter` isn't supported however all streams are buffered so you don't need to buffer anything and the Writer/OutputStreamWriter are supported. This requires some effort, I don't want to discount that but its still way easier than porting to all these platforms manually.

The reasoning behind this is to maximize portability, the larger the API the more bugs and the larger the resulting applications would be when shipped on a platform that doesn't have a compatible VM (e.g. iOS or Windows Phone). It also slows down build times (more class lookups etc.).

The nice thing is that we try to help when you get stuck and if something important is missing its really easy to add both yourself (the project is open source and got a lot of contributions from 3rd parties) and by asking us.